# why is my python for loop in django return just a single value

Tags: python, django, python-requests

```
the django views.py

def quiz_automate(request):
    val=automate_data()
    # print(val['data'])
    get_quiz=Quiz.objects.get(subject='english',exam_type='jamb')
    for data in val['data']:
        print(data['question'])
        d_question=Question(text=data['question'],quiz=get_quiz)
        d_question.save()
        return HttpResponse('saved')`
```

```
the scraped.py function  

def automate_data():
    url = 'https://questions.aloc.com.ng/api/v2/m?subject=chemistry'
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.json()
```

i tried scraping data from a site and it returned multipled values but whenever i use in my django views to store in my postgres database it just store a value instead of multiple values

Comment: ``return`` exits the function, regardless of the loop. You might want to de-dent the return line, so it will be executed after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is tabbed inside of the for loop. So when it hits that line, it will exit the function, thus only saving the record in the first loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this can be comment not ans